# Exception threw out when deserializing self-reference objects while using ISerializationSurrogate

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, binaryformatter, binary-serialization

Exception threw out when I try to deserialize a self-reference object.

> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: "The object with ID 1 is referenced in the link address information, but the object does not exist."

This is my code:

```
class MySerializationSurrogate : ISerializationSurrogate {
    public void GetObjectData(object obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) {
        Console.WriteLine("MySerializationSurrogate.GetObjectData()");
    }
    public object SetObjectData(object obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context, ISurrogateSelector selector) {
        Console.WriteLine("MySerializationSurrogate.SetObjectData()");
        var it = info.GetEnumerator();
        while (it.MoveNext()) {
            Console.WriteLine($"{it.ObjectType} {it.Name} {it.Value}");
        }
        return obj;
    }
}

[Serializable]
class Test {
    int prop { get; set; } = 123321;
    Test me { get; set; }
    public Test() { me = this; }
}

class Program {

    static void Save() {
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        FileStream fs = new FileStream("E:\\a.txt", FileMode.Create);
        Test ch = new Test();
        bf.Serialize(fs, ch);
        fs.Close();
    }

    static void Read() {
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        SurrogateSelector mss = new SurrogateSelector();
        mss.AddSurrogate(typeof(Test), bf.Context, new MySerializationSurrogate());
        bf.SurrogateSelector = mss;
        FileStream fs = new FileStream("E:\\a.txt", FileMode.Open);
        object ch = bf.Deserialize(fs);
        fs.Close();
    }

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Save();
        Read();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

> There wasn't any out put in my console, so I think `SetObjectData()` and `GetObjectData()` hasn't been called.
>
> If I delete `mss.AddSurrogate(typeof(Test), bf.Context, new MySerializationSurrogate());` the code will run successfully.
>
> If I remove `Test.me` the code will run successfully.
>
> I tried to find out what's wrong, so I created a circular reference like this:
>
> > a.p=b;b.p=a;Serialize(fs,a);
>
> and then deserialize, no any exceptions. So circular reference is supported.
>
> It seems that when you use a user-defined *surrogate* and try to deserialize an object that has a self-pointer, the exception will be thrown.
>
> Even your surrogate wasn't called.
>
> So what's wrong?

Comment: I want to run your code so I can see the same thing you're seeing - do you have the `MySerializationSurrogate` code? also, I don't mean to "be that person", but: I **really, really, really** advice against `BinaryFormatter`, in any scenario: https://blog.marcgravell.com/2020/03/why-do-i-rag-on-binaryformatter.html

Comment: `MySerializationSurrogate` is on the top of the code block,  you just need to add some imports. @MarcGravell

Comment: Maybe exception info is a little different, I use Google Translation translated it to English.

Comment: oh, so it is; I must have scrolled down! looking

Comment: I read the article, it said the `BinaryFormatter` has some security and compatible problem. But they are tolerable for me. I just use it to store something simple. I just want to know if I made some mistakes in my code. @MarcGravell

Comment: Nonetheless thank you for giving me advice. I will be prudent with `BinaryFormatter`.

Comment: if you copy the surrogate configuration code from `Read` into `Save`, it all works fine - is that what is missing here?

Comment: emmm...But if add these code in `MySerializationSurrogate.GetObjectData()`: 
   `info.AddValue("prop", ((Test)obj).prop);info.AddValue("me", ((Test)obj).me);`    The problem appears again.@MarcGravell

Comment: you're not imagining it; yeah, that's ... awkward; good question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can get that working is to use a sentinel for manually encoding self-referential payloads:

```cs
    const string Self = "SELF";
    public void GetObjectData(object obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        var test = (Test)obj;
        info.AddValue("prop", test.prop);
        if (test.me is null) { }
        else if (ReferenceEquals(test.me, test))
        {
            info.AddValue("me", Self);
        }
        else
        {

            info.AddValue("me", test.me);
        }


    }
    public object SetObjectData(object obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context, ISurrogateSelector selector)
    {
        var it = info.GetEnumerator();
        var test = (Test)obj;
        while (it.MoveNext())
        {
            switch (it.Name)
            {
                case "prop":
                    test.prop = (int)it.Value;
                    break;
                case "me":
                    switch(it.Value)
                    {
                        case string s when s == Self:
                            test.me = test;
                            break;
                        case Test t:
                            test.me = t;
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
        return obj;
    }
```

Comment: Yes, it really works, thanks. But why this problem appears? If it's not my fault, is there a bug in `BinaryFormatter`?

Comment: But how it can be? `BinaryFormatter` has existed in .Net for so many years!

Comment: @victor12369 I wouldn't consider it a bug; more a case that: if you're assuming control, *you need to assume control*, which includes the problem of self referential data; there may be a way to hack `IObjectReference` into the mix here, so that it can put *something* into the graph promptly ... let me take a peek (edit: nope, couldn't get that working either)